# Controlling which fragment is shown from navDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I am working on this application that has a viewPager and a few swipeable fragments in its MainActivity. Today I implemented navigation drawer but I do not know how to control which fragment is shown from drawer`s DrawerItemClickListener class. Is there a solution or I was just moving in a wrong direction and have to change the way navigation drawer is implemented?

Tutorial suggests to use the getFragmentManager method which does not work for me.

Thanks.

Here is DrawerItemClickListener class:

```
package com.freestylers.druskischool;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener   
{

public int FragmentNumber;




@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long
id) {
    selectItem(position);
}



private void selectItem(int position) {

Fragment fragment = null;

switch (position) {
case 0:
    fragment = new StartFragment();
    FragmentNumber=0;
    break;
case 1:
    fragment = new MesFragment();
    FragmentNumber=1;
    break;
case 2:
    fragment = new NaujienosFragment();
    FragmentNumber=2;
    break;
case 3:
    fragment = new InstruktoriaiFragment();
    FragmentNumber=3;
    break;
case 4:
    fragment = new MetodikaFragment();
    FragmentNumber=4;
    break;
case 5:
    fragment = new GalerijaFragment();
    FragmentNumber=5;
    break;
case 6:
    fragment = new InstruktoriaiFragment();
    FragmentNumber=6;
    break;
case 7:
    fragment = new AtsiliepimaiFragment();
    FragmentNumber=7;
    break;
case 8:
    fragment = new DrufunparkFragment();
    FragmentNumber=8;
    break;
case 9:
    FragmentNumber=9;
    fragment = new KontaktaiFragment();
    break;

default:
    break;
}



if (fragment != null) {
    //tutorial suggests this code:

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    getActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);


} else {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
}
}
}
```

And here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.freestylers.druskischool;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

ViewPager pager;
FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter2; 

/* Just some random URLs
* 
* Each page of our pager will display one URL from this array
* Swiping, to the right will take you to the next page having
* the next URL.
*/
 String[] fragments={
    "start",
    "mes",
    "naujienos",
    "instruktoriai",
    "metodika",
    "galerija",
    "kainos",
    "atsiliepimai",
    "drufunpark",
    "kontaktai"


};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[10];

    drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, 
"Pradžia");
    drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, "Mes");
    drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, 
"Naujienos");
    drawerItem[3] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, 
"Instruktoriai");
    drawerItem[4] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, 
"Metodika");
    drawerItem[5] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, 
"Galerija");
    drawerItem[6] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, 
"Kainos");
    drawerItem[7] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, 
"Atsiliepimai");
    drawerItem[8] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, 
"Drufunpark");
    drawerItem[9] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy,     
"Kontaktai");


    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles= 
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this,     
R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.my_pager);

    adapter2=new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(

            getSupportFragmentManager()
        ){

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // This makes sure getItem doesn't use a position
           // that is out of bounds of our array of fragments
           return fragments.length;
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // Here is where all the magic of the adapter happens
            // As you can see, this is really simple.
            //(fragments[position]);
                if(position==0){
                return StartFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==1){
                return MesFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==2){
                return NaujienosFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==3){
                return InstruktoriaiFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==4){
                return MetodikaFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==5){
                return GalerijaFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==6){
                return KainosFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==7){
                return AtsiliepimaiFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==8){
                return DrufunparkFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==9){
                return KontaktaiFragment.newInstance();

                }       
                else{return KontaktaiFragment.newInstance();}

        }

    };

    //Let the pager know which adapter it is supposed to use
    pager.setAdapter(adapter2);  
}  





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/*@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


    int id = item.getItemId();
    itu f (id == R.id.action_start) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}*/


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

// Handle other action bar items...
/* switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
}*/

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}





public static void ChooseFragment(Fragment fragment) {


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake, it all has to be inside MainActivity.java, DrawerItemClickListener is an inner class.
Still have not found a way to navigate between swipeable fragments from the navDrawer, probably it is impossible.